# Передача постов в array(ObjectId) пользователя Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, express

Всем привет, я новичок, у меня есть проблема..
Есть две модели (Post, User)
Сейчас, пост принимает id юзера и записывает его как author.
Мне нужно сделать так что бы обновлялось поле "posts" у пользователя.
т.е. что бы каждый созданный им пост передавался туда... Как мне можно это реализовать ?
Заранее спасибо.. ;)

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
       name: {
        type: String
        },
     email: {
       type: String,
       required: true
       },
     username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
     password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
     posts: [{
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
        }]
      });


    var PostSchema = new Schema({
    post: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true
    },
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    likes: {type: Number, default: 0}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такое

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  post: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  likes: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  posts: [PostSchema]
});
```